# ImportError: No module named eventlet

Tags: python-2.7, importerror, eventlet

I have installed eventlet library in python using : `pip install eventlet`. But when I tried to import eventlet this error occured:

```
$python 
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import eventlet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named eventlet
```

I tried to install it again but I got this :

```
$pip install eventlet
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): eventlet in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eventlet-0.18.1-py3.5.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): greenlet>=0.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/greenlet-0.4.9-py3.5-macosx-10.6-intel.egg (from eventlet)
```

How to rectify this error?

P.S : I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is not specific to Eventlet, it's just about managing multiple versions of Python on OSX.

Your `pip` command installed eventlet into `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5`, see version.

It means you actually have two Python versions installed: 2.7 and 3.5 and `pip` works with 3.5.

Your options:

- (recommended) use separate virtualenv [1] for every project, explicitly specify python version when creating virtualenv using `virtualenv --python=python2.7 /path/to/new/venv`
- run python3 and use eventlet in latest Python
- run `pip2 install eventlet`
- symlink pip to pip2 `ln -snf $(which pip2) $(which pip)`

[1] http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: Also recommended, use a virtulenv to contain the python interpreter and packages http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: @therefromhere yes, thank you, I inserted virtualenv option into my answer, it's really the best choice

Answer (score 0):

You may also use

`$py -2 -m pip install eventlet`

It worked for me in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pip install eventlet
```

> This worked for me in windows10